# In a 12v automotive system, can a second battery properly sustain charge with a diode?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, automotive, lead-acid

I am working on a 12v system where there is a display/computer that requires voltage to stay above 8V to stay on. Problem is during engine crank the voltage momentarily drops to 5V before regaining.

I am trying to investigate a system with a second battery dedicated for the display (common ground) connected to the main battery through a diode:

[image: Here is the circuit in mind]

In such a system would the second battery sustain charge when it is receiving 14-1.2=12.8V because of the diode? Is this system viable?

Comment: Should be OK. When the alternator charges the main battery at 14.5V or anything up to 15V. the diode will drop that to 13.8V which is a perfectly good float charge voltage. You do need some resistance to limit the worst case charging current to the diode's rating.

Comment: That's an oddly chosen diode to have such a high Vf.  Probably a similar chemistry (eg lead-acid) cell would charge to a fraction of capacity on the receiving end of a more typical diode drop.  But useful systems would probably use another battery type with its own charging circuit.  You might(?) be able to simply use a diode feeding a largish electrolytic capacitor of appropriate voltage rating for automotive use (eg, you might see more than *twice* the nominal battery voltage)

Comment: Hi @Aditya. Welcome to the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. To better understand your question, could you tell me where the 14V? Comes from? Did you mean 12V? Also, 14-1.2 = 12.8 not 13.V. Finally, I think what you call the "2nd" battery is the one on the right? Is that correct?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yikes, subtraction was dumb. The alternator provides 14V nominally, when the engine is running. And yes, the second battery is the one on the right.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A capacitor was the original idea. But concerns regarding lifetime and electrolyte leakage arose. These engines are supposed to last up to 10 years with close to 24x7 operation (I said automotive in question but really it is a stationery engine).

Comment: Put the capacitor somewhere away from heat and start with a quality one from a trustworthy manufacturer and supply chain.  While your concerns aren't unfounded, they're going to be even worse with a lead acid battery.

Comment: @Aditya, you might want to check out schottky barrier diodes. They're just like normal ones, but with a lower forward voltage drop (typically around 0.5V). The reason why you'd use one is a lower forward voltage drop means the diode can handle more current without getting hot. And that's more voltage to the output, too.

Comment: It's possible that this is a bit of an XY problem and the real issue is that your power converter for running the computer off the engine electrical system is ill-chosen.  Eg, it may have too high a dropout, or it may be that what you really need is a "buck boost" such that it can keep drawing energy even when the bus voltage drops under heavy starter load. A better design for the electronics might also be more tolerant of power loss, and retain critical state in some ultra-low-power way able to use a small primary battery (of course with its own maintenance procedure and health status report)

Comment: @ChrisStratton at the moment, the capacitor is pretty much pushed to "only if we have to". Keeping in mind it is more difficult to replace a large capacitor than a battery in the field. The two batteries can sit beside each other and while the leakage hazard exists, the users tend to understand that better. I do like the buck-boost but sourcing a device with such a wide range of input has been difficult.

Comment: @SchuylerHorky that's an interesting idea. Thank you! Investigating right now

Comment: I agree with the others. But, if you decide to pursue other options, there are many. People in the boating and RV worlds deal with these kinds of things often. There are voltage sensing relays and also DC-DC battery chargers that can keep the second battery topped off using a smart charging profile. Etc. FYI.

Comment: I doubt any lead acid battery will last for 10 years. Maybe super premium ones, provided that the ambient temperature is not too high. I would be looking at LFP (aka LiFePO4) batteries. In that case you will need a DC-DC charger for the second battery that is specifically designed for LFP.

Comment: @mkeith While the engines do last that long and beyong with rebuilding and what not, the battery will still be replaced and maintenance is still done. My main motivation behind that statement was a battery is much more replaceable than a large capacitor when it is time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that configuration is viable.  As the commenters suggest, a better (lower Vf) diode is advisable.

This is similar to how car audio fanatics configure their systems.  They have a seperate battery (and capacitor) bank that is powered through a large diode, and a diode to the main 12V battery so that neither system will adversely affect the other.  eg. when starting the engine, or when they are cranking the volume their headlights won't dim.

Comment: Thank you! I will take the diode advice into for sure

Comment: @user263983 In an automotive system charge current is limited as the voltage on the battery increases.

Comment: @user263983 why should they not have the same voltage? Also, adding a resistor would further reduce the voltage that ultimate charges the second battery,  wouldn't that affect the system?

Comment: @user263983  Both batteries are charged via constant voltage.  The second battery is controlled just as much as the first one is.